# Jacoco code coverage: non-existent Static block shows only 75% coverage

Tags: java, unit-testing, code-coverage, jacoco

I have two static methods in the class BrickSortParallel. They are fully covered by unit tests. But I have a static block `static {...}`  listed with only 75% code coverage by Jacoco. What does that signify?

[image: Screen shot of coverage]

```java
public static int computeOddTaskCount(int length) {
    if (length < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal argument value: " + length);
    return isOdd(length) ? length >> 1 : abs(length - 1) >> 1;
  }

  public static int computeEvenTaskCount(int length) {
    if (length < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal argument value: " + length);
    return length >> 1;
  }
```

Following are test cases to ensure full code coverage for above methods:

```java
class ComputeTaskCountTest {

private static final String ZERO_TASKS_EXPECTED = "Zero tasks expected.";
  private static final String ONE_TASK_EXPECTED = "One task expected.";
  private static final String HALF_TASKS_EXPECTED = "Half tasks expected.";
  private static final String ILLEGAL_LENGTH_EXPECTED = "Illegal length expected.";

    @Test
    @DisplayName("BrickSortParallelTest.ComputeTaskCountTest.testZeroLength")
    void testZeroLength() {
      assertEquals(0, computeOddTaskCount(0), ZERO_TASKS_EXPECTED);
      assertEquals(0, computeEvenTaskCount(0), ZERO_TASKS_EXPECTED);
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("BrickSortParallelTest.ComputeTaskCountTest.testMinusOneLength")
    void testMinusOneLength() {
      assertThrows(
          IllegalArgumentException.class, () -> computeOddTaskCount(-1), ILLEGAL_LENGTH_EXPECTED);
      assertThrows(
          IllegalArgumentException.class, () -> computeEvenTaskCount(-1), ILLEGAL_LENGTH_EXPECTED);
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("BrickSortParallelTest.ComputeTaskCountTest.testMinusTwoLength")
    void testMinusTwoLength() {
      assertThrows(
          IllegalArgumentException.class, () -> computeOddTaskCount(-2), ILLEGAL_LENGTH_EXPECTED);
      assertThrows(
          IllegalArgumentException.class, () -> computeEvenTaskCount(-2), ILLEGAL_LENGTH_EXPECTED);
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("BrickSortParallelTest.ComputeTaskCountTest.testMinValueLength")
    void testMinValueLength() {
      assertThrows(
          IllegalArgumentException.class,
          () -> computeOddTaskCount(Integer.MIN_VALUE),
          ILLEGAL_LENGTH_EXPECTED);
      assertThrows(
          IllegalArgumentException.class,
          () -> computeEvenTaskCount(Integer.MIN_VALUE),
          ILLEGAL_LENGTH_EXPECTED);
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("BrickSortParallelTest.ComputeTaskCountTest.testOneValueLength")
    void testOneValueLength() {
      assertEquals(0, computeOddTaskCount(1), ZERO_TASKS_EXPECTED);
      assertEquals(0, computeEvenTaskCount(1), ZERO_TASKS_EXPECTED);
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("BrickSortParallelTest.ComputeTaskCountTest.testTwoValueLength")
    void testTwoValueLength() {
      assertEquals(0, computeOddTaskCount(2), ZERO_TASKS_EXPECTED);
      assertEquals(1, computeEvenTaskCount(2), ONE_TASK_EXPECTED);
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("BrickSortParallelTest.ComputeTaskCountTest.testThreeValueLength")
    void testThreeValueLength() {
      assertEquals(1, computeOddTaskCount(3), ONE_TASK_EXPECTED);
      assertEquals(1, computeEvenTaskCount(3), ONE_TASK_EXPECTED);
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("BrickSortParallelTest.ComputeTaskCountTest.testFourValueLength")
    void testFourValueLength() {
      assertEquals(1, computeOddTaskCount(4), ONE_TASK_EXPECTED);
      assertEquals(2, computeEvenTaskCount(4), "Two tasks expected");
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("BrickSortParallelTest.ComputeTaskCountTest.testMaxValueLength")
    void testMaxValueLength() {
      assertEquals(
          Integer.MAX_VALUE / 2, computeOddTaskCount(Integer.MAX_VALUE), HALF_TASKS_EXPECTED);
      assertEquals(
          Integer.MAX_VALUE / 2, computeEvenTaskCount(Integer.MAX_VALUE), HALF_TASKS_EXPECTED);
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("BrickSortParallelTest.ComputeTaskCountTest.testMaxValueLengthEven")
    void testMaxValueLengthEven() {
      assertEquals(
          (Integer.MAX_VALUE - 2) / 2,
          computeOddTaskCount(Integer.MAX_VALUE - 1),
          HALF_TASKS_EXPECTED);
      assertEquals(
          (Integer.MAX_VALUE - 1) / 2,
          computeEvenTaskCount(Integer.MAX_VALUE - 1),
          HALF_TASKS_EXPECTED);
    }
  }
```

Am I missing anything in the above test class?

The full classes are available at:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/linusjf/DSAlgos/master/src/test/java/ds/tests/BrickSortParallelTest.java

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/linusjf/DSAlgos/master/src/main/java/ds/BrickSortParallel.java

```
$ java --version
openjdk 11.0.8 2020-07-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.8+10, mixed mode)
```

Jacoco version: 0.85

From the report, the static block has a cyclomatic complexity of 2 and with only one branch covered, that implies there's a [test case missing to cover that eventuality](https://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/counters.html).

Comment: Doesn't it tell you which branches have been covered and thus which haven't?

Comment: No,  just static {...} 75% coverage in the html report generated by Maven. When I click on it, it takes me to the first line of the class definition.

Comment: Running your provided unit test in IntelliJ (with JaCoCo coverage runner) displays 100% test coverage for the methods you've pointed out above ([see image](https://imgur.com/iy6zRdD)).  Maybe try `mvn clean` to clear out your project output directory and rerunning your tests?

Comment: Hmm...I expect full coverage as well. That's why I'm surprised.

Comment: @Thomas Should I be using anything other than w3m from the command line to view the report?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with Jacoco but since Omair used the runner in IntelliJ I'd assume it should provide the information you need. What I'm not sure about is whether the reports you got from Maven but since those are html files you might want to use a real browser to view them (w3m might not be able to display everything).

Comment: @Omair This has plagued me over the past two weeks. Mutation coverage (default) via pitest passes the methods as well.

Comment: @Thomas Shouldn't it display 100% coverage though? I'm viewing them through Termux. Is there a way to serve up these files by running a web server in the report directory?

Comment: Yes it should display 100% coverage and thus it's strange that it doesn't. That's why I asked whether it reports covered lines or not. Unfortunately I'm not that familiar with Jacoco and the coverage reports generated by maven since I mostly used Eclipse's coverage tool (not sure what it is using behind the scenes) or SonarQube's coverage view.

Comment: Added the screen shot from the report after serving up the site directory via Apache httpd. Every line green in class BrickSortParallel. class definition line is highlighted as pale yellow.

Comment: Looking at the metrics, the methods have full coverage. But what's the static {...} about?

Comment: It looks like you have a static initialization block, separate from those two static methods you included in your question. You should click `static{}` link in that report in your screenshot to see the specific lines and branches it is reporting as not covered.

Comment: There aren't any, @Mark B. Nor in any base classes. I might have framed the question incorrectly, initially. But the 75% coverage problem is consistently present.

Comment: Clicking on it points to the first line in the class definition , namely class Name extends Parent....

Comment: The only jacoco issue I found is this:https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/issues/568

Comment: The only other reason I can think of is that I'm using the Checkers framework and that modifies the byte code that Jacoco works with. Is that a possible explanation?https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/issues/51

Comment: Well, I decompiled the generated class online and there are no static blocks in that , either.

Comment: Posted an issue to Jacoco Github. https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/issues/1087

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To quote [Marc R Hoffman on Jacoco Github](https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/issues/1087#issuecomment-680002127):

"Your code uses the assert keyword which results in a static initializer:

```
static {};
  descriptor: ()V
  flags: (0x0008) ACC_STATIC
  Code:
    stack=1, locals=0, args_size=0
       0: ldc           #72                 // class ds/BrickSortParallel
       2: invokevirtual #73                 // Method java/lang/Class.desiredAssertionStatus:()Z
       5: ifne          12
       8: iconst_1
       9: goto          13
      12: iconst_0
      13: putstatic     #31                 // Field $assertionsDisabled:Z
      16: return
    LineNumberTable:
      line 19: 0
    StackMapTable: number_of_entries = 2
      frame_type = 12 /* same */
      frame_type = 64 /* same_locals_1_stack_item */
        stack = [ int ]
```

This is a know limitation. The workaround is to not use assert."

The following code snippet resolves the conundrum:

```java
  @Generated
private void assertEquality(int  size, int count) {
if (size != count)
 throw new AssertionError("Size is not the same as count.");
    }
```

It throws AssertionError and yet code coverage requirements are satisfied by the `@Generated` annotation. It is, however, a workaround. The solution is to wait for Jacoco to provide the needed filtering of assertions in the byte code.

[Filtering assertions is a work in progress](https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/wiki/filtering-JAVAC.ASSERT).